# How to set up phpUnit alias for laravel project?

Tags: phpunit, alias, ubuntu-18.04

I installed phpunit using composer to project.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^7
```

It is installed correctly. But how to set up aliases to use

```
~$ phpunit
```

to run all tests.
 I found that `~$ vendor/bin/phpunit` works. Where and how to set up alias for that in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias you talk about is for global use, the `phpunit` inside the vendor folder is for that project only.

**Install PHPunit globally**

Install `PHPunit` globally if you want to use `$ phpunit` everywhere ([more info](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/installation.html)).

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.5.phar
$ chmod +x phpunit-6.5.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit-6.5.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
$ phpunit --version
```

Comment: I would not recommend to install PHPunit globally. Its better to just create an alias, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could just set up an alias in your `~/bash_profile`

```
alias phpunit='vendor/bin/phpunit'
```

Now you can enter

```
~$ phpunit
```

in your project and the local phpunit from `vendor/bin/phpunit` will be executed.